# Intro image not showing up after uploading it to hosting - html/css

Tags: html, css

I've worked on a html/css for a website based on a theme. It works well on other websites and when I open the index/website in my browsers. But once uploaded to my hosting the first image (intro__bg) doesn't load. Everything else including other images work well though.
Can anyone see how to fix this??

(http://test.ar-cs.co/)

thanks!

/A

I've treid reaching out to my hosting but they were of no help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The resource http://test.ar-cs.co/images/intro-bg.jpg gives a 403 error meaning access is denied. You probably need to change the permission of the file with `chmod 775 images/intro-bg.jpg` or configure your web server to allow requests to the `images` folder.